# DynamoDB Friends design

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

I need to create a friends table inside of dynamodb. I am tryng to decide how to design the table and looked over what once of Amazon's team member recommend.

http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/amazon-dynamodb-design-patterns-for-ultrahigh-performance-apps-dat304-aws-reinvent-2013-28436991

They reccommend a 2 way relationship:

```
Friend 1 | Friend 2
-------------------
BOB      |   ALICE
ALICE    |   BOB
ALICE    |   JOHN
```

Then you can query on Friend 1 to get all the friends. The problem I see is this is not transnational. For example say BOB doesn't want to be friends with ALICE anymore. We would need to delete 2 records so that when BOB and ALICE query their friends list they don't show up in either list. The problem is what if only one deletion operation is successful (e.g network loss or throughput exceeded)? Then say for BOB Alice is still a f friend, but for Alice BOB is no longer a friend. It is inconsistent. I think this would be very bad practice. Am I missing something, because this would be an ideal design for me, but this problem for me would make it not acceptable? My thought would be to have a one way relationship, but then create a global secondary index on Friend 2 so that way I would double my reads (1 read on the table and 1 on the index) but there would be only one item for the relationship and it would be safe if say I needed to delete it as there would only be only one item to delete if either BOB or ALICE want to no longer be friends. Is the recommended solution good and I am missing something or is there flaws and is there a better solution? I would like to avoid global indexes if I could as it automatically doubles my costs, but currently I do not see a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the solution that was mention in the link, imagine this there are 100 users which makes another 100 friends you have make 100*100*2 write operation on the table. It is more likely that people will make friends on  daily basis but removing a friend would be far less compared to adding them. In this solution you can avoid any indexes as well as you have stated earlier.

Now your problem for deletion

```
Solution 1:
AWS has introduced Lambda which would be effective in this, configuring with
DynamoDB on deletion of row you can trigger a lambda function which will 
check if both the operation was performed successfully or not.

Solution 2:
Rather then directly removing the row from DynamoDB put the request in a SQS queue, 
A reader will read the message and remove both the records.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not too familiar with AWS, so will Lambada or SQS guarantee the transaction? Say Lambada or SQS try to make the operation and it get rejected because the dynamodb provision is exceeded, will it automatically retry until it succeeds or how does it work that makes it different from calling dynamodb directly?

Comment: @user2924127 SQS is a queuing system that will guarantee that message will be delivered at least once, you can check if the operation is successful, then remove the message else try again. This would not be same in case of Lambda